How to properly handle text stream response from backend to frontend
I have implemented BE on node/express js and FE on Next js.
I have a POST request API route that takes users' data and generates some text responses.
The final answer is generated by LLM which can be streamed with stream:true. Now, I want the answer to be streamed in my Frontend too. I tried to implement it but I am having some problems here.
BACKEND CODE:
for await (const chunk of llmStreamResponse) {
      res.write(chunk || '');
    }

 

    const { dataArray, anotherDataArray} = formatData(someArguments);

    res.end([
      { data: [...dataArray, ...anotherDataArray], type: 'data' },
      { data: req.sth, type: 'sth' },
    ]);

FRONTEND CODE:
if (!response.ok) {
    const responseError = await response.json();
    throw responseError;
  }
  //@ts-ignore
  const reader = response !== null && response.body.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  const trueValue = true;

  while (!!trueValue) {
    //@ts-ignore
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
    console.log(chunk)
     
  }

The problem I am facing is although I have sent different chunks using different res.write function but I get multiple strings joined sometimes and sometimes single res.write is also broken down into different chunks.
This is making me unable to perform json.parse on the array data.
I wanted to receive data in format {data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"} but couldn't due to this chunk overlapping or breaking problem.
the received data if short data is kept is like this
`
{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}{data:"sth", type:"data_type_name"}

AND if long then it is split into multiple chunks.
I wanted the data to be received uniformly as I send from the BE.
